# PHP echo printing language construct

Tags: php, html, output, echo, submit-button

***In an assignment I'm having trouble running a php script with page handling. It's outputting actual php code when submitted through another php page but works fine on its own.***

I have a **html login page** which submits via submit buttons rather than form submit [a requirement]. This submits to **login.php**. 
Seperately I have **testBalance.php** which checks a file **balance.txt** on my server which simply has an amount (1000). testBalance.php calls a function in **getBalance.php** to return the amount here.

***THE PROBLEM IS*** when I run **testBalance.php** by itself it works just fine. Displaying "Account Balance: 1000.00" but when I attempt to set (in **login.php**) **testBalance.php** as the redirect url, the page literally displays code from my testBalance.php page: "Account balance: "); printf ( "%01.2f", $returnValue ); echo ("
"); ?> " I know it's convoluted, this is an intro to php portion of an web prog. class. I'm guessing it has to do with the value pairs that are being passed through to the pages. Can anyone help?

**LOGIN.HTML snippit**

---

```html
 <input type="button" name="sub_but" id="bal"   value="check balance"
 onclick="location.href = 'login.php' + '?' + 'name='+ document.forms[0].username.value + 
 '&amp;redirectURL=' + 'bal';" />
```

**LOGIN.PHP**

---

```html
<?php
    $NAME=$_GET["name"];
    $PAGE=$_GET["redirectURL"];
    $DESTINATION="";

if ($NAME == ''){   /* HANDLES NAME ERRORS */
    echo "PLEASE RETURN AND ENTER A NAME.";
    }
elseif (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $NAME)) === false) {
    echo "$NAME is not a valid name. Name must contain letters and spaces only";
    }
else{
    if($PAGE=='with'){
        $DESTINATION = "withdraw.html";
    }
    elseif($PAGE=='bal'){
        //$DESTINATION = "balance.html";
        $DESTINATION = "testBalance.php";
    }
    elseif($PAGE=='depos'){
        $DESTINATION = "deposit.html";
    }
    elseif($PAGE=='weath'){
        $DESTINATION = "weather.html";
    }
    elseif($PAGE=='xchang'){
        $DESTINATION = "currency.html";
    }
                                                       /*echo("$DESTINATION\r\n");*/
    
    header("Content-Length: " .
    strlen(file_get_contents($DESTINATION)));
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    readfile($DESTINATION);
    }
?>
```

**testBalance.php body snippit**

---

```html
        <?php
            include 'getBalance.php';
            $returnValue = readBalance();
            echo "<p>Account balance: ";
            printf( "%01.2f", $returnValue );
            echo "</p>";
        ?>
```

**getBalance.php**

---

```html
 <?php
    function readBalance(){
        $file = "balance.txt";
        $fp = fopen($file, "r");
        if (!$fp){
            echo "<p>Could not open the data file.</p>";
            $balance = 0;
        }
        else{
            $balance = fgets($fp);
            fclose ($fp);      
        }
        return $balance;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Code snippets are being overused, misused and abused. Who came up with this idea anyway?

Comment: I recognize it's overkill, but I figured that without there would be tons of comments asking why I didn't include relevant code.

Comment: The code is fine, it's the (code) snippet buttons.

Comment: Ah, yeah I was wondering about that. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: TBH, I couldn't say. I'd have to test it out with a test question in order to see if Stack adds that in by default.

Comment: Ok, Stack added a new button called "Code snippet" in their editor. I guess it's their way at automatically indenting code for the people who do not know or aware of how to indent code (4 spaces or more, followed by code). It has its pros & cons I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readfile()` doesn't EXECUTE anything it reads. It's literally just slurping in the file's bytes and spitting them out to the client. It's basically doing

```
echo file_get_contents(...);
```

If you want your other files to be executed, you need to `include()` or `require()` them instead. Or you could try `eval()`, but you really don't want to go down that route. eval() is evil and dangerous.